# Deleting files and folders in a folder with batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to remove all files and folders in a directory because I want to make a program to switch the files of two folders to be shown in another folder. I know there are threads like this, but I couldn't find any answer where the folder itself isn't deleted.

And I can't just make the folder after deleting because I don't know which and how many folders are in this directory.

That's the code:

```
@echo off
title Change forge version   
::1.8 Mods are selected and will now be replaced
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\1.7_mods\*.*"') do (
    echo 1.7 mods will now be copied into mods folder
    echo and 1.8 mods will be copied back to 1.8 folder
    echo Press a key to continue
    pause >nul
    xcopy /e /s "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods" "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\1.8_mods"
    del "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods" /Q /S
    xcopy /e /s "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\1.7_mods" "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods"
    del "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\1.7_mods" /Q /S
    goto END
)
::1.7.10 mods are selected and will now be replaced
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\1.8_mods\*.*"') do (
    echo 1.8 mods will now be copied into mods folder
    echo and 1.7 mods will now be copied back into 1.7 folder
    echo Press a key to continue
    pause >nul
    xcopy /e /s "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods" "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\1.7_mods"
    del "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods" /Q /S
    xcopy /e /s "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\1.8_mods" "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods"
    del "C:\Users\Florian\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\1.8_mods" /Q /S
    goto END
)
:END
    echo press any key to close
    pause >nul
```

And I need that at del the subfolders are also deleted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a directory with all subdirectories use `rd /s /q "c:\directory"`

Comment: But the folders aren't deleted by this, are they?

Comment: Have you tried it? The command does exactly that - deletes folders (directories).

Comment: Oh sorry thought about another command. The problem in this case is that I want the folder, in which the other folders (that should be deleted) are, to stay.

Comment: Simply create it afterwards: `md "c:\directory"` if you don't care about keeping its old date.